# How to avoid duplicate conditional @testable imports in Xcode Unit Test files?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, preprocessor-directive

I have an Xcode project that has multiple targets including two unit test targets.

I also have set a few `Active Compilation Conditions` flags to determine which target is being compiled in order to attach Unit Test targets dynamically.

For instance: Say my project has App Targets A, B and C as well as Unit Test targets D and E.
I have set up my project such that D and E can dynamically set their `TEST_HOST`, meaning the test bundle can be used on A, B and C, depending on a flag passed into `xcodebuild` command.

Currently, I have to define boilerplate conditional testable import statements for all my test files in D.

Eg:

```
#if FLAG_1
    @testable import MODULE_A
#elseif FLAG_2
    @testable import MODULE_B
#else
    @testable import MODULE_C
#endif
```

where `MODULE_A`, `MODULE_B` and `MODULE_C` are Product modules names for targets A,B and C.

Is there a way I can define these conditional testable targets in one file, and import it in every other test file so that the imports look cleaner (and will be easy to maintain in case I need to add a new condition)?

I guess what I'm asking is if I could define something like:

```
//CommonImports.swift

#if FLAG_1
    @testable import MODULE_A
#elseif FLAG_2
    @testable import MODULE_B
#else
    @testable import MODULE_C
#endif
```

and then use it as an import in my test classes like:

```
//DateTests.swift

import XCTest
import CommonImports

class DateTests: XCTestCase {
   func testExample() {}

}
```

Is this possible with Swift?

Comment: You can do this with normal imports (see [`@_exported`](https://forums.swift.org/t/what-does-exported-import-do/35869)), but not @testable imports.

Comment: Want to check if you got a solution for this. I also had a similar issue in my application

Comment: @Gangadhar Unfortunately not. We're struck with this boilerplate import statement for now.